# How to do multiple inserts to SQL table with foreign key relationship safely with delete first insert if second insert fails

Tags: sql, knex.js

I have these tow tables:

```
CREATE TABLE cities (
        city     varchar(80) primary key,
        location point
);

CREATE TABLE weather (
        city      varchar(80) references cities(city),
        temp_lo   int,
        temp_hi   int,
        prcp      real,
        date      date
);
```

I am using PostgreSQL with Knex JavaScript Driver

While doing an insert transaction, how can do i ensure that if i get an error in inserting in table weather after inserting in table cities, i can go back and delete the insert in table cities to ensure database integrity.
Please i just need a glimpse of what i can do.

Comment: What rdms are you using? (mysql, oracel,mssql)

Comment: *How can i insert ensure deletion of a city* ... this piece doesn't make much sense. Can you try rephrasing?

Comment: Hello, I have edited the question folks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write **AFTER INSERT** `trigger` ON `weather` table.
As your `city` is primary key in `cities` table, when Insertion in `weather` table fails, you can delete entry from cities table using **WHERE** condition- `city = NEW.city`.

NEW.city indicates the value of city which was currently being inserted in weather table and insertion has been failed.

Comment: @KeyurPanchal in this case using triggers is wrong solution. It might work in some cases, but it is a wrong tool for the job. If question would be how one opens a bottle of wine, one could use for example a shoe to open it by tapping the bottom of the bottle with it, but the correct answer should be using a corckscrew. 

Leaving this as accepted / promoted answer with votes would be just confusing for people who are looking for right solution.

Comment: @MikaelLepistö: It would have been better to come on party day to open bottle yourself rather than teaching how to open bottle after half the month of the party. Ask Danstan to to try and select your answer if he finds it correct and helpful.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe I understood the questiong wrong, but it sounds like a basic case of using transactions. Just start transaction, do the inserts and if any of the inserts are failing rollback. With `knex` you can do it like this (http://knexjs.org/#Transactions):

```
knex.transaction(trx => {
  return trx('cities')
    .insert({
      city: 'inari',
      ... rest of the fields ...
    })
    .then(() => {
     return trx('weather').insert({
       city: 'inari',
       ... rest of the fields ...
     });
    });
})
.then(() => {
  console.log('inserted 2 rows');
})
.catch(err => {
  console.log('one of the queries failed, no rows were inserted and transaction was rolled back')
});
```

You shouldn't be using triggers for this.

Comment: This time it kind of did... one should never do the functionality described by OP with triggers. It is just misleading to show that option for beginner programmers who actually might think that it is a good idea.